# Using Raster calculator with ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am making a model in ModelBuilder and there is a problem with Raster calculator result. I have to rasters with 0 and 1 values, I want to know where do they intersect and make a new raster with value 1 in that places. In Raster calculator I put the expresion like: raster1 * raster2. The problem is that it returns empty raster (with 0 values only), but when I look at rasters I can clearly tell that they do intersect.

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem can be?

Comment: Make sure the projection are the same, just in case

Comment: There is same projection, but thanks to your comment I will check the resolution.

Comment: That could also be a good reason :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem with different resolutions :) The problem is solved

Answer (score 4):

In order to do what you are trying to achieve you need to do a 2 step process:

1. Use Raster Calculator and calculate Raster1 + Raster2.

This will give you a new raster with:

Values of 0 where both Raster1 and Raster2 have values of 0.

Values of 1 where one of Raster1 or Raster2 has a value of 1 and the other has a value of 0.

Values of 2 where both Raster1 or Raster2 have a value of 1.

The cells with a value of 2 are the ones you are interested in.  But you said you want these to have a value of 1.

2. You can now use the [Reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) tool to reclassify your new raster.  Using this tool you can reclassify you raster so that all values of 2 become 1.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might also need to reclassify the cells with a value of 1 to something else so that you can still differentiate between these and your new value 1 cells.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, I want new raster values to be "1" where old raster values "1" intersects and "0" in other cases.

Comment: Have changed my answer accordingly.  When using the reclassify tool, just reclassify the 2's to a 1.

Comment: It sounds like OP's problem was unrelated, but in the general case, why would we expect addition to work when multiplication fails? Is this a workaround to a known bug with multiplication, or is something else at play?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the OP wants. The OP seems to be interpreting 0 as "no value at this location." So "intersection" would be the cells where both rasters have a non-zero value, no?